# Get an array with a Hash's pairs in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

Given a hash, I'd like to get an array with all of its pairs.

This should work:

```
hash.select{true}
```

I couldn't find a builtin method to do this, which I find pretty strange since it does look like a reasonable operation I'd usually need. Is there a simpler way to achieve this? (OK I know that the above code is already simple, but I wonder if Ruby has a more standard way to do this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Hash#to_a](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-to_a)

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/kirti/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > h = {1 => 2}
 => {1=>2} 
1.8.7 :002 > h.to_a
 => [[1, 2]] 
1.8.7 :003 >
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, use [`to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Hash.html#method-i-to_a) method (read as: `to array`) on your Hash:

```
hash = { :a => 3, :b => 5 }
hash.to_a
#=> [[:a, 3], [:b, 5]]
```

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 don't support `hash = { a: 3, b: 5 }` :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit: and, I was wondering why I hated the number `1.8.7`! updated :P